Why doesn't vapour pressure depend upon the amount of liquid?
I was reading about the Clausius-Clapeyron Equation, which is as follows:

I was also reading about Vapour Pressure, when I learned this:

The vapor pressure of a liquid does not depend on the amount on [sic] the liquid in the container, be it one liter or thirty liters; at the same temperature, both samples will have the same vapor pressure.

I do get the fact that yes, from the Clausius-Clapeyron equation, I can see that there is no dependence of vapour pressure on anything other than temperature. However, I am still not able to understand why the equation doesn't have any parameter or variable linked to the number of moles or amount of liquid.
Like, if I take 5 moles of liquid and 10 moles of liquid (at the same temperature), it just looks like there will be more pressure for the 10 moles. However, thats not true. Can anyone explain, please?

The increasing of a condensed substance amount does not have the same effect as increasing substance concentration in solution or its partial pressure in gas. For the former, its chemical potential is still the same, for the latter, it grows.

Is it not that the two phases are at equilibrium, and this  equilibrium can only happen when molecules of the first can move into the other and vice versa, so if you suddenly increase volume the vapour pressure falls temporarily then rises until it is again at its equilibrium value, temperature being held constant.

This is a case where it may help to understand the equilibrium in kinetic rather than thermodynamic terms. Equilibrium occurs when the rate of condensation of molecules from the gas to liquid phase is equal to that of evaporation of molecules from the liquid to gas phase.
Both reactions can only happen at the gas-liquid interface, so they are dependent on the surface area rather than the volume of both the liquid and gas phases. Since the surface area is typically is not written explicitly in the rate expressions, the dependence is not obvious.

@porphyrin why does increasing the volume of liquid cause a temporary decrease in vapour pressure? Like If I add some liquid using whatever means, shouldn't the vapour pressure increase suddenly and then the reaction proceeds backwards?

Pressure, assume $pV=RT$. Suddenly the equilibrium is broken as the volume is increased. In reality it takes time for the molecules to evaporate  and more have to do so than condense to reach equilibrium again. This may not take that long but it is not instantaneous. At any instant, whether or not at equilibrium, both evaporation and condensation happen , there is no 'reaction proceeding backwards' both forwards and reverse events always happen just at different rates when not at equilibrium.

okkk thanks got it.
